# How to loop over folders in a directory and take input into a list then print

Tags: command-line, bash, printing

I have directories named from 3 to 8. In each one there is a file called OUTCAR. I need to grep a number from this file as:

```
grep Elapsed OUTCAR|egrep -o "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+"
```

The lines in question look like that:

```
Elapsed time (sec): 45123.137
```

So, at the end I want to print two columns as the directory name and `egrep` output like:

```
3 80650.077
..
8 42757.057
```

For example when I elapse in folder 3 with `grep Elapsed OUTCAR|egrep -o "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+"` I get `80650.077`
Many thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `grep` and `sed`:

```
grep -oP 'Elapsed time \(sec\):\K.*' {3..8}/OUTCAR | sed 's_/OUTCAR:__'
```

This uses the brace expansion `{3..8}/OUTCAR` to construct this list of arguments to the `grep` process:

```
3/OUTCAR 4/OUTCAR 5/OUTCAR …
```

`grep` searches these files for matching lines and outputs only the part after the colon with the relative file path and name. `sed` removes the unwanted file name part from every line, leaving just the directory name and the match (which already contains a space).